# Does anyone know what the name of this tree is?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]This tree started growing near our home about 5 years ago (volunteer). The tree has a very upright growth pattern and the branches are short and perpendicular to the trunk. It is quite polite, even though it is close to the house, the branches are not touching it.

We would love to know what kind of tree it is, as we would like a few more for our home in the country. We live in Noblesville Indiana.

See attached photos

Thank you!
Donna Barnes[image]

[image]

Comment: the fruit almost looks like a loquat.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an ornamental or "flowering" pear. Pyrus calleryana. I see it has brown fruit on it that looks like what an ornamental pear produces. Were the flowers white and fishy smelling? If so, that's it.

Comment: Yes, flowering pear. I would probably go as far as "Bradford Pear". Usually young bradford pear trees have a different shape (more rounded), but we have a tall one like yours - as does our neighbor. Both are older trees. It is possible they have been looked after more than normal (they tend to suffer damage easily). They look nice in bloom, but otherwise I'm not a fan of them. Break easily, attract grackles and not much else, suckers.

Comment: Should also add: They're fast growing. Hence their fragile nature. Also combined with the blossom, they're very popular in the Dallas-Fort Worth area at the moment (we're now further north).